# How can i loop through bootstrap tooltips forever using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have some thumbnails on my site, that use Twitters Bootstrap tooltips to display the name of each thumbnail, what i'm trying to do is loop through each one, with a delay of say 2 seconds showing the tooltip, then hiding it as the next one pops up. I tried to do this a few ways but nothing was working.

I got as far as something like this, but that wasn't working.

```
$("[rel=tooltip]").each(function (i) {
      $id=$(this).attr('id');
      $($id).tooltip('show');
  });
```

Here's a JSFiddle of my layout: http://jsfiddle.net/BWR5D/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var ttid = 0, tooltipIds = [];
$("a[rel=tooltip]").each(function(){
    tooltipIds.push(this.id);
});

var iid = setInterval(function(){
    if (ttid) $('#'+tooltipIds[ttid-1]).tooltip("hide");
    if (ttid === tooltipIds.length) ttid = 0;
    $('#'+tooltipIds[ttid++]).tooltip("show");
}, 2000);
```

- You can stop the tooltips from showing with: `clearInterval(iid);`

Comment: I can't seem to get this to do anything more than produce errors. Can you edit the JSFiddle to get it working? Thanks

Comment: I mistyped the tooltipIds array name on one line. Code has been updated. Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/say2joe/BWR5D/5/

Answer (score 0):

Following should hide current open tooltip, then show the next. Uses current index vs length of cached elements to determine when to start back at beginning

```
/* cache elements*/
var $els=$("a[rel=tooltip]").tooltip(), index=-1;

var tipLoop=setInterval(function(){
    index++;
    index =  index < $els.length ? index : 0;
    $els.tooltip("hide").eq( index).tooltip('show');    
},2000)
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/BWR5D/1/

Comment: That's great, but after the first loop, the tooltips show for less than a second and then disappear, any way to fix that?

Comment: not sure what's causing that, seems like bug in bootstrap. Try using valid html , `div` is not valid child of `<a>`. Also not sure that you aren't asking for conflict problems when user hovers an image

Comment: Preferably i'd like it to pause and resume when the user hovers. And divs are only there as placeholders for now.

Comment: suggest creating your own and not using bootstrap. Have more control when user interacts with images. Can stop an animation if use your own code. Can use bootsrtap css and html structure to make it easy. Only a couple extra lines of code needed and maybe a slight adjustment to html structure