# Boostrap 3 clipboard and tooltip with dynamic ID

Tags: jquery, tooltip, clipboard, zeroclipboard

I have the following code, but I need all the ID with #coupon to work with dynamic post ID, for example: `#coupon-3567`

```
jQuery('#coupon').tooltip({
  trigger: 'dblclick',
  placement: 'top'
});

function setTooltip(message) {
    jQuery('#coupon').tooltip('enable');
  jQuery('#coupon').attr('data-original-title', message).tooltip('show');
}

function hideTooltip() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('#coupon').tooltip('hide');
    jQuery('#coupon').tooltip('disable');
  }, 2000);
}

var clipboard = new Clipboard('#coupon');
 
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  setTooltip('¡Copied!');
  hideTooltip();
});

clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
  setTooltip('Error');
  hideTooltip();
});
```

I have modified the html code to get the ID, but I don't know how to make the ID work in the JS, I have tried for many hours and I have not succeeded.

```
<div id="coupon-<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>" class="cnt-cpn-bd" data-post-id="<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>" data-clipboard-text="<?php the_field( 'coupon_code', get_the_ID() ); ?>">
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713609/how-can-i-loop-through-bootstrap-tooltips-forever-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```html
<div id="coupon-444"></div>
```

You will get the Id with

```js
console.log($('[id^=coupon]').attr('id'));
result: coupon-444
```

Then use

```js
var id = $('[id^=coupon]').attr('id');
$('#' + id).tooltip({
  trigger: 'dblclick',
  placement: 'top'
});

function setTooltip(message) {
  var id = $('[id^=coupon]').attr('id');
  $('#' + id).tooltip('enable');
  $('#' + id).attr('data-original-title', message).tooltip('show');
}
```

For hide

```js
function hideTooltip() {
  var id = $('[id^=coupon]').attr('id');
  setTimeout(function() {
     $('#' + id).tooltip('hide');
     $('#' + id).tooltip('disable');
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: That's not what I need, I need the IDs to work with a real post ID, example: ´# coupon-2534´ (2534 is the post ID). My javascript code works fine, I just need to do the integration with those dynamic IDs.

Comment: So the tooltips will be correct initiated. I created an coupon-id for each element.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bernhard Beatus, it works fine, the only problem is that when I click on any div ID, the tooltip always shows in the first div, but it doesn't show in the desired div. Can you help me with that problem please?

Comment: updated my answer. Should work now. Just get the id before the tooltip function

Comment: I have updated the code, but the problem persists. If you want I can show you the website so you can check it.